# Upgraded angular to 15 with rxjs installed but packages complaining rxjs dependencies are missing

Tags: angular

Getting very frustrated! I have updated angular and all packages to 15, when i then try to serve the app which worked fine on version 8 i'm now getting this:

```
Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The target entry-point "ng-socket-io" has missing dependencies:
 - rxjs/Observable
 - rxjs/add/operator/share
```

But as you can see in my package.json i have rxjs installed, which was exactly the same (just older version) before i updated everything.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^15.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "^15.1.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.1.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.31.0",
    "angular-flatpickr": "^3.6.6",
    "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^5.0.1",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^7.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "emoji-js": "^3.7.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^11.0.0",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^3.0.0",
    "ngb-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "^0.1.6",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^14.0.2",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^16.0.2",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "twemoji": "^14.0.2",
    "ws": "^8.12.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.12.0",
    "zxcvbn3": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.1.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.1.5",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-socket-io` is an old project that hasn't been updated in 5 years and is probably not compatible with v15 since it relies on RxJS 5 (!!!!)

Comment: i don't even know why i have that installed i use socket.io-client. Either way, if i remove it, ng4-loader-bar also produces a similar issues with rxjs/Obervable and rxjs/Subject. I can't just remove every package i need

Comment: It's the same problem. You have deprecated dependencies that you will need to drop. There is no alternative